# How do software versions are ported (or not) in a LTS version?

Tags: upgrade, lts, versions

I run 18.04 on my main server and I have a hard time to exactly understand what "LTS" means:

- does "Long Time Support" mean that whatever software is installed on day one, at that "version", will be supported together with all the upgrades of this software?
- or that whatever is installed on day one will stay at that "version" ?

When running an `apt list --upgradable` I see, among others

```
python3-distupgrade/bionic-updates,bionic-updates 1:18.04.24 all [upgradable from: 1:18.04.21]
```

This means that the version moves from `18.04.21` to `18.04.24`, therefore it changes - at least for the most minor part.

**What exactly (from software version perspective) changes in time with the LTS?**

Note about "marked as duplicate": my question is not about [the *timing* of the support](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16366/whats-the-difference-between-a-long-term-support-release-and-a-normal-release) (which is the essence of the other answer) but about the **versions of the software** which make an LTS.

As an example, `python` on my 18.04 servers is `3.6.5`. The current stable version is `3.7`. Will I get it? Or only updates of `3.6`? Is there a rule which states how the evolving versions of a program will or will not be ported to an LTS?

Comment: @karel: not really a duplicate. I am aware that the exact version I want may not be available **yet** (or available via a PPA) - my concern is whether it will be available **at all** because of the rules around updating (or not) software in  LTS (= the core of my question) and how this is decided (maybe because this is a security fix and then it goes in, or maybe because there is a functional bug, or because there is a new feature but it is backward-compatible, ...)

Comment: I think the answer to my question is "SRU" (description found in https://wiki.ubuntu.com/StableReleaseUpdates) and the actual information is that there is no rule for whether a package will be updated, but it will probably not be.

Comment: The top answer to the duplicate question suggested by @karel explains when and why package versions are frozen and what kind of a updates Canonical ships for them. The same rules apply for LTS releases with the exception of kernel and X.org packages which are back-ported from all future releases up to and including the following LTS release (but need to be installed manually). Thus I agree with his duplicate.

Comment: @DavidFoerster: I read this answer once again and the sentence which mentions the versions is *"Updates for potential security problems and bugs (not new versions of software)"*. It applies to both LTS and non-LTS versions. Which would mean (to take the example of Python) that whatever is defined as "version" in python (the x in 2.x and 3.x) will only change between releases (LTS and non-LTS alike). Is this the correct interpretation? If so my understanding is that there is nothing special in LTS (in the context of the versions shipped with the release) = they do not change

Comment: (cont'd)  (again, depending on what "version" means for a specific software)

Comment: Yes, that's correct with the exception of kernel and X.org packages as outlined above or when it's too difficult do back-port security fixes alone (e. g. in the case of Firefox).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Package version updates policy](https://askubuntu.com/questions/224894/package-version-updates-policy)